# MS-Word Foot Note automatically changes the Font whenever I click on Print Preview or convert to pdf

Tags: microsoft-word

I had used the footnote as part of referencing in about 60 pages word document. In this footnote, I also used the cross reference (linking with other numbering and text that were heading 2 or heading 3 styles). When I tried to convert to pdf or at least, click on print preview - the footnote font automatically changes. Please see below 2 images for easy understanding (before & after).

I also tried formatting the styles but to no avail.

I am unable to find the solution - a kind of option to disable the automatic change of the fonts of the footnote.

[Before Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr39C.png)

[After Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKbWY.png)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is something way beyond an option that needs setting. From your screenshots, I can see that in addition to the change of font you mention, there are also what look like section numbers appearing in front of two of the footnote numbers. It seems that either your document has become corrupted, or you have encountered a bug in Word.

My recommendation is to exit Word, make a backup copy of the document, and then attempt to repair your document using [the Microsoft guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/damaged-documents-in-word). If that doesn't help, you should report it to Microsoft as a possible bug, requesting support.

Failing all else, or as something to try if you end up waiting for a response from Microsoft, try creating a brand new document and using copy and paste to copy your existing text to the new document. If the same problem occurs at any point, repeat the process, stopping before the trouble point, and perhaps continuing at a later point. This trial-and-error approach may enable you to recover much or all of your work in a fairly short space of time.